# Как сформировать список с вложенным списком из базы mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет. Не могу никак додуматься как сформировать список с вложенным списком. По сути дела, есть в базе таблица с категориями товаров и подкатегориями. Нужно вывести список так, чтобы подкатегории были вложенным списком категории к которой они относятся. Ребята помогите пожалуйста. Второй день сижу с этим меню. Я учусь только не кидайтесь камнями)
Должно получиться вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня получилось вот так:

```html
<?php 
    $query = "SELECT 
                c.id AS categories_id,
                c.category AS categories_category,
                sc.id AS subcategories_id, 
                sc.subcategory AS subcategories_subcategory,
                sc.category AS subcategories_category
            FROM subcategories sc
            RIGHT JOIN categories c ON c.id = sc.category";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die (mysqli_error($link));
    for ($data = []; $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); $data[] = $row);
    var_dump($data);
    $content = '';
    foreach ($data as $elem) {
         $content .= "<li class=\"sub\">
                        <a href=\"\">$elem[categories_category]</a>
                    </li>";

            if ($elem['categories_id'] == $elem['subcategories_category']) {
                $content .= "<ul>
                                <li class=\"down_item\">
                                    <a href=\"\">$elem[subcategories_subcategory]</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>";
            }
    }




?>
```

Ну и результат соответственно вот такой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Начнём с того, что у вам не нужна отдельная таблица с подкатегориями. Достаточно ввести столбец `parent_id`, если он `NULL` то это категория. Соответственно, когда вы выбрали все записи из БД, то вам полученный массив нужно пересобрать так, чтобы подкатегории были вложены в категории (на SO был такой вопрос "древовидное меню"). После этого проблем с выводом не возникнет.

Comment: Спасибо. Направили на путь верный и получилось... Можете отвечать, поставлю галочку))